# Unity 3d, What Universe.physicsTimeStep is?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i was trying to duplicate [this solar system simulation project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7axImc1sxa0&t=604s) and i have a question:

[image]

What is "Universe.physicsTimeStep"? i searched in unity manual and scripting API but i didn't found anything. Can someone explain me? Thanks

Comment: This is not Unity built-in but something the maker of your tutorial implemented somewhere ...

Answer (score 1):

Historically, when games simulated physics, they did so by updating the physics simulation once every frame. For example, to find distance travelled they would use velocity * timeStep, where timeStep is the time between frames.

Nowadays, especially with multithreaded game engines, the physics simulation runs (somewhat) independently of other simulations and rendering. For example, the rendering could be done at 60 frames per second but the physics is only updated every other frame (i.e. 30 FPS). The more frequently the physics simulation is updated (i.e. the lower the time step), the more accurate the physics simulation is.

Sometimes, the time steps of various systems are adjusted so that the game rus 'properly' even when the hardware is a limiting factor. Typically this is done by 'dropping' (i.e. skipping) render frames, but update frames could be dropped as well. Some games, especially platformers and other games where physics is very important, will always run the physics simulation with the same time step so that running it on a slower CPU (which would result in a higher time step) doesn't affect gameplay, such as by making difficult jumps easier.

In your case Universe.physicsTimeStep seems to be the time step used for updates in the game. It also appears to be a fixed time step, so it will always be the same. If the game is running slowly, it will drop render frames but keep updating the physics.

Answer (score 0):

That is a public constant in the class Universe(You should see Sebastian Lague's Solar System Github repository.
It's clearly mentioned there